# Rails rendering a different view depending on the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, renderpartial

I have a tab navigation page in my rails app which is shared across all of my views. Inside I have a small text area which should change depending on the page that the user is on.

Currently I am doing this by adding a variable to the controller and using it in the render partial path, like so:

```
class Myapp::WebsitesController < MyappController
  def set_up
    @page = 'websites/left_text_info'
  end
```

and then in my partial:

```
<%= render :partial => @page %>
```

This works but it doesn't feel like the best 'ruby' way of doing things. Can anyone advise on a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `controller_name` helper method directly in your view and skip the controller part:

```
<%= render "#{controller_name}/left_text_info" %>
```

Or if the only thing that change is the content of the textarea, then perhaps the best way is to define a helper method that returns only the content for it, so you don't need multiple partial files that are very similar.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def text_area_content
    case controller_name
    when "users"
      "content for users"
    when "articles"
      "content for articles"
    else
      "other content"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, both of these seem cleaner than adding the path to the controller as I was doing previously.